# Why this simple subquery gets wrong results?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have table with documents nammed: `z_web_dok` it has `133,369 rows`, the other table with products nammed: `z_web_dok_art` has `693,930 rows`, all fields needed for querying are indexed, and connection between those tables is auto increment field of `z_web_dok.oid` and `z_web_dok_art.oid_id`.

**What is the problem?**

I were made simple sql query for returning old prices (by buyer, place, country). The query is:

```
SELECT (COALESCE(NULLIF(TNew.cijena_e,''), TNew.cijena)*(TN.kurs_iznos/1)) 
    FROM z_web_dok_art As TNew 
    INNER JOIN z_web_dok As TN ON TN.oid=TNew.oid_id 
WHERE (TN.Drzava='BiH' AND TNew.aid='SOME_PRODUCT_ID' AND TN.vrsta_dok='pri' 
      AND TN.kup_id='1047' AND TN.mag_id='5' AND TN.oid<>'151967') 
ORDER BY TN.dat_zavrsena DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

and it worked, for each product, so i used it inside another query, which gets products their new prices and with the query above (subquery) i tried to pull the old prices (Connection was between tables: `TNew.aid=WArt.aid` )

```
SELECT WArt.aid, WArt.nc, WArt.isp, COALESCE(NULLIF(WArt.cijena_e,''), WArt.cijena) As cijena, WArt.rab, WArt.vpc, WArt.mpc, C.EAN, C.Model, C.Naziv, C.JM, C.WebBiH, C.DostupnostBiH, 
(
  SELECT (COALESCE(NULLIF(TNew.cijena_e,''), TNew.cijena)*(TN.kurs_iznos/1)) 
  FROM z_web_dok_art As TNew 
  INNER JOIN z_web_dok As TN ON TN.oid=TNew.oid_id 
  WHERE (TN.Drzava='BiH' AND TNew.aid=WArt.aid AND TN.vrsta_dok='pri' 
         AND TN.kup_id='1047' AND TN.mag_id='5' AND TN.oid<>'151967') 
  ORDER BY TN.dat_zavrsena DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) As s_cijena 
FROM 
z_web_dok_art As WArt 
LEFT JOIN Cjenovnik As C ON C.ID=WArt.aid 
WHERE WArt.oid_id='151967' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN WArt.isp='0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, WArt.id_dok_art
```

It worked, for a long period, but today we discovered it returned 6 times higher result for old price for two products (on a order that has 19 products).
So i were query `TN.oid` with same query to see what does it pulls from database and it was oid that has following fields same: (`kup_id, vrsta_dok`) but all others are different even if the query asked for `Drzava='BiH' AND TN.mag_id='5'` it doesn't return results for that.

But the other problem is, if i execute subquery as query alone, with that product (or more them) **it returns RIGHT RESULTS**. But above one mixed results right and wrong one.

**It's not problem in solving this!**

**I can solve it, but i wanted to know why this QUERY didn't work, i mean, what's the problem with it? Did anyone had problem with this?**

This is my first bad experience with similar queries...

I were thinking about, it's happening because of subquery JOINS with another table inside of query (because the subquery works perfect without it's parent query).

Thank you for your time!

```
Best regards,
Nedžad.
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE (25.10.2016):**

```
The server mysql version: 5.5.52-cll
Local version mysql: 5.6.17 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)


Localhost returned the proper results, with NO MISTAKE,
while the server mysql still returns wrong results..
```

Is it bug at mysql 5.5.52-cll or what?

Image of results:
[image]

**UPDATE: (SOLVED)**
And i solved it by using group in subquery:

```
GROUP BY TNew.oid_id, TNew.aid
```

- (grouping by, documents, and products inside of it), and it returned the right results - the performance was good, 0.1704 (which is good because it's always one document at opening). Once again, thanks everyone which were lead me to right path

Comment: I am not sure how your data is stored, but I need to clarify this: could your  subquery return multiple rows for the same date? Why am I asking this? `ORDER BY TN.dat_zavrsena DESC  LIMIT 1`. If your query returns more then 1 row for the same _dat_zavrsena_ you can not be sure how it will be sorted. I hope you understand what I mean by that.

Comment: Doesn't look like a simply query to me! There are too many variables for me to attempt to debug. I suggest you try to reproduce the problem which a much smaller set of data involving the minimum number of tables and columns possible.

Comment: @moni_dragu but how i understand mysql, it should first return rows, then doing order and limiting, and my query was saying i need Drzava='BiH' and it returns results for 'Other country!' - but localhost is working perfectly!

Comment: @onedaywhen I will try to reproduce the same bug at smaller table, i will do it today when i get a little time. Thanks.

Comment: I think the point @moni_dragu makes is important. If the sub query prior to the LIMIT can return more than 1 row with the same date, then which of those rows that is returned is not defined. Quite likely it will depend on something random, such as the order the rows were inserted which might well be different between live and the localhost copy. Can you post some test data to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: As i said, i will give my best to make error again (online, so you guys can see it), and for localhost & server, it's the same database, i just copied to see results on different mysql.

Comment: I can't get the same bug on a simplier table with lower records, only what do i get is different prices (that could be caused because of "dat_zavrsena", but in the query above that's not only problem, the problem is that it returns different "Drzava" (HRV) instead of (BiH) what i asked in subquery.... Which i can't get as a bug on a simpplier table..

Comment: Thank you guys, it looks like you were right about datetime sort..., when i used: `GROUP BY TN.dat_zavrsena ORDER BY TN.dat_zavrsena DESC` i got right results, but query was slow, about 15 seconds.. but i will change the way it works anyway.. Thank you all!

Comment: And i solved it by using group: `GROUP BY TNew.oid_id, TNew.aid` - (grouping by, documents, and products inside of it), and it returned the right results - the performance was good, 0.1704 (which is good because it's always one document at opening). `Once again, thanks everyone which were lead me to right path`